# Arreglos en Java ordenados alfabéticamente

Tags: java, array

Estoy haciendo una tarea de programación en *Java* donde tengo dado de alta el usuario y tengo un `case` para consultar mis usuarios, pero me piden que al hacer mi consulta me muestre la consulta ordenada alfabéticamente. Este es el código del `case` de consultas:

```
case 2:
    System.out.println (Arrays.asList(clientes));
    String consulta=sc.next();
    for(i=0;i<clientes.length;i++){
        if(consulta.equalsIgnoreCase(clientes[i])){
            existe=true;
            if(existe){

                break;
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
// ...
```

Comment: puede emplear `Arrays.sort` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(byte[]) .Saludos

Comment: ¿Por casualidad tus datos vienen de una base de datos? Hago la pregunta abriendo la posibilidad de que los traigas ya ordenados en el resultado: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1883291/5587982

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar la utilidad `Collections.sort()`. Por ejemplo:

```
Collections.sort(Arrays.asList(clientes));
```

Creo que es la mejor forma de solucionarlo ya que mezcla mayúsculas y minúsculas.

Answer (score 2):

Aparte del método ya mencionado, con `Collections` tambien te ofrece un comparador que ignora minúsculas/mayúsculas en el ordenamiento:

```
Collections.sort(Arrays.asList(clientes), String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

Ten en cuenta que este ordenamiento no considera diferencias de Locale. Si se necesita comparación basado del locale puedes usar un comparador con [`Collator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html):

```
import java.text.Collator;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Comparador implements Comparator<String> {

    private Collator collator;

    public Comparador(Locale locale, int fuerza){
        collator = Collator.getInstance(locale);
        collator.setStrength(fuerza);
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        return collator.compare(s1, s2);
    }
}
```